# Read a DBF db using javascript (or some cordova plugin)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dbf

I have a *.DBF file made for an old application, and now I'm trying to make a mobile version of this application using cordova, I spent three days looking for some method to read this file, but I could't find any!

So... Is this possible?

Ps.: My English is a little bit rusty! ^^

Comment: I'd suggest you do a one-off migration of the .dbf file to something more commonly used with android, such as SQLite.

Comment: Yes... I changed the mobile application to read a JSON file with the previously converted info from DBF DB, anyway I will need to teach the user to do this, OR I will create a vb.net application to convert from DBF to JSON... because he will need to do this more than one time!